# Python - count the number of words in text file that are also in csv word list

Tags: python, csv, text

I have this code which counts how many times the words from "wanted" appear on text file..

```
import re
import collections
from collections import Counter

wanted = "fish chips steak"
cnt = Counter()
words = re.findall('\w+', open('textFile.txt').read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in wanted:
        cnt[word] += 1
print cnt
```

I would like instead of giving the words myself, to be able to counting the number of words in the .txt file that are in a csv file

```
import re
import collections
from collections import Counter

wanted = "CsvFileWithWords.csv"
cnt = Counter()
words = re.findall('\w+', open('textFile.txt').read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in wanted:
        cnt[word] += 1
print cnt
```

How can I do that?

Comment: seems like you just need a way to turn `"CsvFileWithWords.csv"` into a string which contains all the words in the file. What's wrong with `open(file_name).read()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read CsvFileWithWords.csv and put its words in a list. You can do the same you are doing to get the words in textFile.txt.

```
wanted = re.findall('\w+', open('CsvFileWithWords.csv').read().lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
csv=open("csvfile").read()
wordlist=csv.split(";")
for i in wordlist:
    wanted +=" "+i
```